# Remove file name from path in Automator

Tags: pdf, applescript, automator

I'm creating an automator service that will mark my invoices as paid... I've got a workflow that gets selected PDF, sets variable to path of PDF, Watermarks it, then returns it to it's original location. However the final step doesn't work as the path variable links to the PDF rather than a folder.

Please help.

[image: workflow]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the workflow?

Comment: "then returns it to it's original location". I don't understand when the file has been initially moved. You select files in a Service by control clicking them and then selecting the service in the menu.

Comment: When watermarking a file it moves it to a temporary location, so I have to use the 'move finder items' to return the file. But the variable set early returns a location like '~/Desktop/file.pdf', so I have to remove the 'file.pdf' from the path, but I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 3):

You can get the parent folder of your input like this:

[image: myFolder]

```
on run {input}
    tell application "Finder" to set myFolder to (container of (first item of input)) as alias
    return myFolder
end run
```